# Best library for PHP Sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, kohana

I have been using the CodeIgniter system for a while now - but [it has](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/120042/#594699) it's [short comings](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/100098/). I am grateful for what it taught me, but now I need a library for a new non-codeigniter project and so I am looking around for ideas on which libraries have things right and which don't. I will probably have to take pieces from several libraries to get everything I need.

I just took a look a the [Kohana PHP session](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/session) library and I like how it returns to the native PHP way of using the $_SESSION superglobal instead of forcing a change to $this->session for data access.

At any rate, I wanted to know if there were other good session libraries out there I might be messing. There is a lot that must be handled in a session besides just CRUD functionally.

- Support for NON-cookie based session passing (i.e. Facebook or Flash uploaders)
- "Flash data" that only lasts for the next page load and then is auto-removed.
- Works with $_SESSION or $this->session so that programmers don't have to change existing code.
- Supports setting a new session id (i.e. session_id('new id')) in case you want to change the id mid-way through the page.
- Saves all data at the end of the page request instead of each time data is added or removed (saves extra DB queries).
- Supports using files, cookies, or Database for storage. (or memcached would be nice)
- Attempts to deny access in case of a session hijack. (IP, useragent, or [fingerprint](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/EckoSession/))

I just spent some time going over the logic for the CodeIgniter and Kohana session libraries and I came up with the following on how each starts and ends sessions for the page.

```
/**************
** Kohana Sessions
**************/
If not native file storage {
    session_set_save_handler to the storage type (DB, cache, cookie...)
}

set the session_name() so php knows what cookie value to check

start session

/****** Saving ******/

session_write_close() which calls the given handler


/**************
** CI Sessions
**************/

Try to read_session() -> {
    session = Get cookie (if using cookies will also contain data)

    if(database) { 
        session .= pull data from database
    }

    checks if valid...

    $this->userdata = session data

} else { 
    create a new one
}

/****** Saving ******/

session data is serialized either way

if(cookie) {
    save cookie with serialized data and params like "last_activity"
}
if(database) {
    save serialized data in db and session in cookie
}
```

Comment: +1. This have been in my mind for sometimes now. Thanks for laying it out in details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you have a look at [`Zend_Session`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/index.html#zend-session)?

- you can pass the session identifier via URL using PHP settings
- you can expire certain session variables by time or by hops (requests)
- migration into other apps won't be that easy and I think it's not very good when you mess with `$_SESSION` when you use `Zend_Session`
- `Zend_Session` has an adpater based-approach for saving session data. A [save-handler](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.save-handler.html) for DBs is included, but its architecture allows for custom handlers to be passed in.
- `Zend_Session` supports validators to check the validity of a session. Here too we have an open architecture that allows you to pass in custom objects for validation.
- you can lock a session, aka make it read-only
- you can prevent the instantiation of multiple instances of the same session namespace
- plus there is a lot more to discover with `Zend_Session` such as regenerating session ids, issue remember-me-cookies, revoke remember-me-cookies and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Zend usually covers all of their bases so it is great code to check. However, at 10 files just for a session handler - I think I will pull some of the better parts so I don't mess anything writing my own. 

The Zend Session class seems to follow closer to the Kohana class by relying on the $_SESSION superglobal and setting session handlers - which definitely seems like the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this in CI: [EchoSession](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/EckoSession).

Comment: Thanks, but like I said this won't be for a codeigniter project. Actually, I had already downloaded that library while looking at Zend_Session and many other session libraries. By reviewing the code from each one a pattern is starting to emerge as to what "best-practices" are for session handling.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, After digging through the custom, non-$_SESSION-based codeigniter lib, the two Kohana and Zend libs (which use $_SESSION), and several other session libraries from other projects I believe that I build the answer to my problem. Something that satisfies all of the things I listed above (except flash data).

[Here is the code](http://github.com/Xeoncross/micromvc/blob/c2eb579463f9462a3aa941d91d4f85ecd0551e81/libraries/session.php) if anyone wants to use it or read it while building their own library. I left a lot of comments thoroughly explaining the whole thing and would love to have some feedback on it. It supports tokens, flash based uploaders, cookies, session regeneration every 5 mins (or whatever you set) with removal of old sessions, and support for storing sessions in any database, the file system, memchache, or any other form that you want to set.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [Zebra_Session, a wrapper for PHP’s default session handling functions, using MySQL for storage](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-session/)

- acts as a wrapper for PHP’s default session handling functions, but instead of storing session data in flat files it stores them in a MySQL database, providing better security and better performance
- it is a drop-in and seemingless replacement for PHP’s default session handler: PHP sessions will be used in the same way as prior to using the library; you don’t need to change any existing code!
- implements row locks, ensuring that data is correctly handled in scenarios with multiple concurrent AJAX requests
- one file only
- mature, highly optimized and constantly developed
- [very good documentation](http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/docs/Zebra_Session/Zebra_Session/Zebra_Session.html)